# How to get any user posts using facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I only can reach to my posts with API but I can not reach to friends posts so I want to fetch all the public posts from a user with my user access token. 
to be clearer I want to get the users post AND his friends posts.

Comment: You can't get posts from users that hasn't granted user_posts to your app. It is very simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. For privacy reasons, the Facebook API won't give you most information unless the user who owns that information - not their friends, even if it's technically part of the "public profile" - explicitly grants permission by connecting to your application with the right permissions.

Comment: I tried to get read stream permission but I can not, Facebook monopoly read stream for itself.

Comment: @aliAtwa There's no privacy violation in Facebook using data that was given to Facebook. There is with apps - just because my friend uses your app doesn't mean I want you to have my data. Facebook has continued to move in this direction - it's not changing any time soon.

Comment: what ceejayoz said. also, there is no read_stream permission anymore.